# Why Task.Delay doesn`t work in this situation

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm testing the `async` and I found this situation that I can't understand:

```
var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);

    return 2;
});

var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Task.Delay(1000);

    return 1; 
});

await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);

var result = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

I would like to understand why the result is always 0! Why is not 1000, 2000 or the sum of the two tasks 3000? Why  doesn't `Task.WhenAll` wait for the completion of the tasks?

Comment: @GrantThomas I'm trying to assign it to a variable but it gives me a compiler error, how can I do this?

Comment: @MuriloKunze To answer that question we'd need to see the line of code and the error.

Comment: I tried this: var taskresult = await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);
But it gives me a 'Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable'..

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Okay, so, the second one is the easy one, so let's handle that one.

For the second task, `t2`, you don't do anything with the result of `Task.Delay(1000)`.  You don't `await` it, you don't `Wait` it, etc.  Given that the method is not `async` I supposed you meant for it to be a blocking wait.  To do that you'd want to add `Wait()` to the end of the `Delay` call to make it a blocking wait, or just use `Thread.Sleep()`.

---

For the first task, you're being bitten by the fact that you're using `var`.  It's clearer what's happening when you don't use `var`:

```
Task<Task<int>> t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);

    return 2;
});
```

You're returning a task of task of `int`, not just a `Task` of `int`.  The outer task is "completed" as soon as the inner task finishes being started.  When you use `WhenAll` you don't care about when the outer task finishes, you care about when the *inner* task finishes.  There are a number of ways to handle this.  One is to use `Unwrap`.

```
Task<int> t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);

    return 2;
}).Unwrap();
```

Now you have your expected `Task<int>` and `WhenAll` will take at least 2000 milliseconds, as expected.  You could also add in another `await` call to do the same thing:

```
Task<int> t1 = await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);

    return 2;
});
```

As mentioned by svick [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071606/) another option would be to just use `Task.Run` instead of `StartNew`.  `Task.Run` has a special set of overloads for methods that take a `Func<Task<T>>` and return a `Task<T>` and automatically unwrap them for you:

```
Task<int> t1 = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);

    return 2;
});
```

For this reason it's preferable to use `Task.Run` as the default option when you're creating async lambdas as it will "handle" this issue for you, although it's best to be aware of it for the complex cases where you can't use `Task.Run`.

---

Finally we come to the option that you didn't do, which is what you probably should be actually doing in this case.  Since `Task.Delay` already returns a Task, there's no need to put it in `StartNew` in the first place.  Rather than creating a nested task and using `Unwrap` you can just not wrap it in the first place:

```
var t3 = Task.Delay(3000);
await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3);
```

If you actually just want to wait for a fixed amount of time that's what you should be doing.

Comment: There is another option: use `Task.Run()`. It unwraps the task by itself, so it's probably a better option than using `StartNew()` combined with `Unwrap()`.